# Transactional replication on dedicated server using AG Listener

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, alwayson, availability-group

I have dedicated server to setup transactional replication.

i want to replicate 3 tables only Availability Database.

The tricky part is, I want my transactional replication to continue automatically if automatic failover happen.

Is there any way to achieve this plan?

Transactional replication to continue even the failover happen on availability database.

Comment: MS have [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for that. Is there a particular point in there that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Hi Ben. Please share the links. Seems i could not find it.

Comment: I did - that word "docs" in my previous comment is a hyperlink to what I believe is the relevant documentation.

Comment: Hi Ben,  thank you so much. have successfully setup the transaction replication with FO capability. Now i have another question. Is the any way that the distributor server to have FO capability?

Comment: You're in luck! In that same document linked to above, there's a reference to another one. Search it for "Configure distribution database in an availability group".